# Unix script. How can I search for a keywords in a file and another one remove the entire line?

Tags: bash, unix, git-bash

I am new on this and I would really appreciate any help.
I need to write a Unix code to search a string in a file X, after that search in the file target removing the lines found before...

I have made several attempts like the following, but it does not work.

```
grep -v "Invalid key: " issues.txt > translate1.stf ; mv translate1.stf  issues.txt
```

Best Regards,
EB

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgJpx.png)

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please don't post images of text; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Looks like you are trying to delete any lines with "Invalid key: " If this is the case. you are better off using one command, namely sed.

Comment: Even from your image it is not clear what you want to achieve. The input contains lines like `Invalid key: CustomLabel.Something. Some error message.` The part `CustomLabel.Something.` is marked, but this does not match the (unclear) description "this information after the first point and the second one." Please clarify in your question what the relevant strings are. THe image shows "This information I have to search in another file"  Show also this "another file"  in your question. And "If exist I have to delete the entire line". From the file shown in the image? From the other file?

Comment: I think I understand your request. You want to delete any line in fileX where the string between "Invalid Key:" and the next period ('.') is contained in fileY. Does that sound right?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps it is not clear. I will try again.
I have two files. The first one I can find everything and the second one it is the log file errors...  For exemplo:

FileX (All things)
FileLogError (Invalid keys from the FileX)

So I have to be able to search for the lines from the FileLogError in the FileX, and if I find, I have to delete the entire line.

Is it more clear?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: One more explanation:

FileX 
Value 1 - Label value 1
Value 2 - Label value 2
Value 3 - Label value 3
Value 4 - Label value 4
Value 5 - Label value 5


FileLogError 
Invalid key: "Label value 2"
Invalid key: "Label value 5"

I have to be able to clean the FileX and at the end will be like this.

FileX 
Value 1 - Label value 1
Value 3 - Label value 3
Value 4 - Label value 4

Tks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request, you want to delete any line in fileX where the string between "Invalid Key:" and the next period ('.') is contained in fileY.

This can be done in `awk`.

If fileX is named "input.txt" and contains

```
Line 1
Invalid Key: Key1. this line shows
Line 2
Invalid Key: Key2. this line is filtered
Invalid Key: Key3. this line is filtered
Invalid Key: Key4. this line shows
Line 3
```

and fileY is named "keysToFilter.txt"

```
# lines containing these keys are deleted
Key2
Key3
```

and a program in file "filter"

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  while (getline < "keysToFilter.txt") {
    keys[$0] = 1
  }
}

# lines matching 'Invalid Key' get this treatment
/^Invalid Key: / {
  keyStart = length("Invalid Key: ") + 1
  keyEnd = index($0, ".")
  key = substr($0, keyStart, keyEnd - keyStart)
  if ( !(key in keys) ) {
    print $0
  }
  next 
}

# every other line is unfiltered  
{ print }
```

... then the following will send a filtered version of `fileX` to `stdout`

```
$ cat input.txt | ./filter
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps it is not clear. I will try again.
I have two files. The first one I can find everything and the second one it is the log file errors...  For exemplo:

FileX (All things)
FileLogError (Invalid keys from the FileX)

So I have to be able to search for the lines from the FileLogError in the FileX, and if I find, I have to delete the entire line.

Is it more clear?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: One more explanation:

FileX 
Value 1 - Label value 1
Value 2 - Label value 2
Value 3 - Label value 3
Value 4 - Label value 4
Value 5 - Label value 5


FileLogError 
Invalid key: "Label value 2"
Invalid key: "Label value 5"

I have to be able to clean the FileX and at the end will be like this.

FileX 
Value 1 - Label value 1
Value 3 - Label value 3
Value 4 - Label value 4

Comment: May I suggest that, instead of using comments to add addtional explanations, you edit your question? Put the sample contents of the 2 files in separate blocks, like I did with my answer.